# Add optional button to edit commit message on Gitlab merge request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, merge-request

Is there any way how to add some "button" to discussion on merge request to update commit message?

We are using second system to reading commit messages - in case commit message including `#foo` (it is optional) we will trigger some notification.

So I would like to add some option "Would you like to add `#foo` into your commit message" - YES | NO into my MR.

Or is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Merge Suggestion in Project’s settings>>merge requests:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#merge-request-settings

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/discussions/index.html#configure-the-commit-message-for-applied-suggestions